# Comparing lists of different types

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists as follows

```
List<MyObject1> list1
List<Long> list2
```

The list2 is basically the list of Id's of MyObject1 which is a property in the object

```
Public Class MyObject1 implements Serializable{

    private Long myObjId;
     .....
      .....
      //other elements go here

   public Long getMyObjId() {
    return myObjId;
    }

    public void setMyObjId(Long myObjId) {
    this.myObjId = myObjId;
}
```

I want to compare the two lists to check if all the objects in list1 are contained in list2

One way is to iterate over the list1, create a new list of Id's out of it and then use the containsAll method on it.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Is this Java 8, or Java 7 and lower?

Comment: @markspace because lambdas

Comment: More details could be necessary. Should the check return "true" when list2 contains (1,2,3) and list1 contains objects with IDs (1,2,2,3)? In any case, creating a list of IDs is feasible and simple, but depending on the exact preconditions and requirements, there may be more elgant solutions.

Comment: I am using java 7, and yes, it should be true if list1 contains (1,2,3) and list2 is (1,2,2,3). essentially list2 has everything in list1 plus anything else.

Comment: My question was the other way around (but may be there are no duplicate IDs, as the name "ID" suggests...)

Comment: I don't see anything better than your suggestion (iterate over list1, then use containsAll()) for Java 7.

Comment: As such none of the lists will contain duplicates. But the problem is, I have two lists on Objects, and 1 of Ids. The Ids list can be either from one list of Objects or other. And I have to repeat this process on multiple such lists. That is why I am looking to simplify the solution instead of creating Id lists every time for both Object lists

Comment: you can iterate through IDs and compare with list2 ids so no need to create other list

Comment: Pier-Alexandre - do you mean creating a Map<Ids, Object>, and then compare the keySet of the Map with the List of Id's? Creating the map will again require iterating over the list of Objects and putting it in the Map. Almost the same. Tell me if I got you wrong

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can write what you described: "One way is to iterate over the list1, create a new list of Id's out of it and then use the containsAll method on it." in one line as:

```
list1.stream().map(a -> a.getMyObjId()).collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(list2);
```

`map` converts a each MyObeject to an id by calling a.getMyObjectId and `collect` creates a list 
as a result.

Comment: *"... check if all the objects in list1 are contained in list2"* - isn't your snippet doing exactly the opposite?

Comment: Then it will be the other way around: list2.containsAll(...). The snippet was supposed how to achieve the conversion in one line.

Comment: I am not using Java 8 though :(

Comment: or Collectors.toSet for more efficiency? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two conceptually different approaches:

- One could collect the IDs in a list, and work on the resulting list
- One could do the check on-the-fly

The first one would boil down to something like

```
boolean allIdsContained(List<MyObject> myObjects, List<Long> validIds) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (MyObject m : myObjects) ids.add(m.getID());
    return validIds.continsAll(ids);
}
```

The second one could be written as

```
boolean allIdsContained(List<MyObject> myObjects, List<Long> validIds) {
    for (MyObject m : myObjects) {
        if (!validIds.contains(m.getID()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that the method signature is the same in both cases, so you are free to change the implementation according to your needs. Particularly, if the list if `validIds` is large, then it could be more efficient to first convert it to a `Set`. (The `contains` method on a `List` is O(n), whereas on a `Set`, it is O(1)). Then the method could be implemented as

```
boolean allIdsContained(List<MyObject> myObjects, List<Long> validIds) {
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>(validIds);
    for (MyObject m : myObjects) {
        if (!set.contains(m.getID()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

In any case, all these methods could be written more concisely with Java 8 Lambdas, but I think that this should be an implementation detail, and should be hidden in such a helper method regardless of how it is implemented.

Comment: I tought that the OP already tried that because: he mentioned that: "One way is to iterate over the list1, create a new list of Id's out of it and then use the containsAll method on it."

Comment: Correct me, but I think he is looking for a simpler way to achieve the this solution..

Comment: I wanted to point out that there is an alternative solution that works without creating a new list, and may have a better performance, but also tried to emphasize that there is hardly a "simpler" solution, if "simpler" does not only mean to make it more concise with lambdas, for example.