# Java 8: More efficient way of comparing lists of different types?

Tags: lambda, comparison, java-8, java-stream

In a unit test, I want to verify that two lists contain the same elements. The list to test is build of a list of `Person` objects, where one field of type `String` is extracted. The other list contains `String` literals.

One often finds the following code snippet to accomplish this task (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641261/comparing-lists-of-different-types/27641329#27641329)):

```
List<Person> people = getPeopleFromDatabasePseudoMethod();
List<String> expectedValues = Arrays.asList("john", "joe", "bill");

assertTrue(people.stream().map(person -> person.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(expectedValues));
```

The `Person`class is defiend as:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

In the example above, the list of persons (or people) is transformed to a list of Strings using Java 8 techniques and the comparision is done in the old-fashioned way.

Now I wonder, if there is a more direct or more efficient way of doing the comparison using other Java 8 statements, for example `allMatch()` or some `Predicate<T>` or something else.

Comment: Why not use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/) matchers instead?

Comment: Do you really want to check `containsAll`? So the order and the size of the lists may be different?

Comment: @TagirValeev I want to ensure that the `List<Person> people` contains all the people that I specify in the static list by comparing their unique names. So the order of the lists may be different but for successful assertion, the size of the lists should be the same.

Comment: @Makoto Using Hamcrest matchers I don't know how to get the `name` property of the people for comparision, since I can't override the `equals` method of the `Person` class.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the code snippet is working as expected. I only want to know if there is a shorter way using Java 8 streams and lambdas and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterating and filtering two lists using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490418/iterating-and-filtering-two-lists-using-java-8)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your question’s code does not reflect what you describe in the comments. In the comments you say that all names should be present and the size should match, in other words, only the order may be different.

Your code is

```
List<Person> people = getPeopleFromDatabasePseudoMethod();
List<String> expectedValues = Arrays.asList("john", "joe", "bill");

assertTrue(people.stream().map(person -> person.getName())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(expectedValues));
```

which lacks a test for the size of `people`, in other words allows duplicates. Further, using `containsAll` combining two `List`s in very inefficient. It’s much better if you use a collection type which reflects you intention, i.e. has no duplicates, does not care about an order and has an efficient lookup:

```
Set<String> expectedNames=new HashSet<>(expectedValues);
assertTrue(people.stream().map(Person::getName)
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet()).equals(expectedNames));
```

with this solution you don’t need to test for the size manually, it is already implied that the sets have the same size if they match, only the order may be different.

There is a solution which does not require collecting the names of `persons`:

```
Set<String> expectedNames=new HashSet<>(expectedValues);
assertTrue(people.stream().allMatch(p->expectedNames.remove(p.getName()))
           && expectedNames.isEmpty());
```

but it only works if `expectedNames` is a temporary set created out of the static collection of expected names. As soon as you decide to replace your static collection by a `Set`, the first solution doesn’t require a temporary set and the latter has no advantage over it.

Comment: I admit that I also have a check for the sizes of the lists but I did not write it in the question's code. And you're right about using sets instead of lists. Your second solution is what I expected to get. But as you said there is no advantage over your first solution, I choose this one. But now I'm using `assertEquals` instead of `assertTrue`.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of elements must be the same, then it would be better to compare sets:

```
List<Person> people = getPeopleFromDatabasePseudoMethod();
Set<String> expectedValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("john", "joe", "bill"));
assertEquals(expectedValues, 
    people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

The `equals` method for properly implemented sets should be able to compare different types of sets: it just checks whether the contents is the same (ignoring the order of course).

Using `assertEquals` is more convenient as in case of failure an error message will contain the string representation of your set.

Comment: Yes, using sets absolutely makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the equality of 2 lists of Person

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  //constructor, setters & getters 
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) return true;
    if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false
    Person p = (Person) o;
    return name.equals(p.name);
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(name);}
}

// call this boolean method where (in a service for instance) you want to test the equality of 2 lists of Persons.
public boolean isListsEqual(List<Person> givenList, List<Person> dbList) {
  if(givenList == null && dbList == null) return true;
  if(!givenList.containsAll(dbList) || givenList.size() != dbList.size()) return false;
  return true;
}

// You can test it in a main method or where needed after initializing 2 lists    
boolean equalLists = this.isListsEqual(givenList, dbList);
if(equalLists) { System.out.println("Equal"); }
else {System.out.println("Not Equal");}
```

I hope this can help someone in need.