# Java 8: Compare multiple attributes in two lists

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

I just started to use Java 8 in a new project and now I'm trying to convert some older code.

I'm trying to convert to following code fragment. It's for a frontend test and simply compares, if there is the product (code) with the correct quantity in `productElements`:

```
for (Product product : products) {
    boolean productFound = false;
    for (ProductWebElement productElement : productElements) {
        if (productElement.getProductCode().equals(product.getCode())) {
            Assert.assertEquals(product.getQuantity(), productElement.getQuantity());
            productFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // This is optional - can be ignored
    if (!productFound) {
        fail("Product: " + product.getCode() + " not found!");
    }
}
```

`Product` is just a normal data class (`String productCode, int quantity`)

`ProductWebElement` is a extended object of [`FluentWebElement`](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium) - or just an object with some additional attributes.

I tried to extend 
[Java 8: More efficient way of comparing lists of different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330688/java-8-more-efficient-way-of-comparing-lists-of-different-types),
but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Does anyone know how to do this in Java 8 syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the following code:

```
products.forEach(p -> {
    ProductWebElement productElement = productElements.stream().filter(
        pe -> pe.getProductCode().equals(p.getCode())
    ).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new AssertionError("Product: " + p.getCode() + " not found!"));
    Assert.assertEquals(p.getQuantity(), productElement.getQuantity());
});
```

For each of your products, we try to find any matching `ProductElement` (having the same product code).

If none is found, we throw a `AssertionError`. If we found one, we can assert that the quantities are the same.

Answer (score 3):

You should get rid of the double iteration in general. One way to do it, is to store the values in a `Map`:

```
Map<ProductCode,Quantity> map=productElements.stream().collect(
  Collectors.toMap(ProductWebElement::getProductCode, ProductWebElement::getQuantity));

products.forEach(product -> {
    Quantity q=map.get(product.getCode());
    if(q==null) fail("Product: " + product.getCode() + " not found!");
    Assert.assertEquals(product.getQuantity(), q);
});
```

Note that since the actual types of your properties don’t show up in your question, I used `ProductCode` and `Quantity` as placeholders here. Further note that I stored the actual quantity property values in the map, as that’s the only value you are interested in, thus there is no need to query the `ProductWebElement`s again in the second loop.

This logic could also be implemented using ordinary pre-Java 8 loops…